# C description of the USB 3.0 protocol constants

Tags: c, usb

I need to write a small USB 3.0 isochronous audio-class device firmware.

I have skimmed through the standard, have some examples in front of me. So I'm pretty ready to start coding.

And here comes the first hurdle. In the examples, the descriptors are expressed as byte arrays. This is terrible!

What I am looking for is a loosely-licensed **C description of the USB 3.0 descriptors**.

Example application code:

```
#include <hollygrauil.h>
const usbDeviceDescriptor d1= {
                              bDeviceClass=USB_DEVDESC_CLASS_AUDIO,
                              etc ... 
                              }
```

Comment: Why the close vote? I am asking about library recommendation!

Comment: What platform are you running on Linux, Windows? Just out of curiosity, why would you need to write this driver - as far as I know usbaudio drivers already exist and implement what is necessary. In general you might check the driver kit, or headers for your platform to see if there is anything already defined for you. If you can't find anything quickly you might just need to read the USB3.0 spec and implement the descriptors yourself, they shouldn't be too involved or difficult.

Comment: @Preston, what difference one word can make! I actually need to write the device-side software (corrected in the question). I am also considering writing the thing myself. It's just strange that such a common thing has not yet been released in the public domain.

Comment: @Vorac I think you must be much more detailed about the environment in which your firmware runs, i.e. more information about your device. Typical USB hardware does a lot of things in ... hardware, and it's also common with middleware from device manufacturers (for SoC-type hardware at least).

Comment: @unwind, the specifics of the project are a separate thing. I just want the numbers from the specification laid out in a bunch of .h files.

Comment: @Vorac, I see now. Typically this is something provided by the vendor of your device, and that will vary from company to company and really depends on how well their USB sample code is written. It sounds like what you have to go off of isn't the best - I don't have much to add from the device side but maybe looking at competitors sample code may help you? Good luck.